# How to append <li> tag at the top inside <ul> with help of jquery in laravel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, laravel, laravel-5

I am developing notification dropdown for my website. for that i am trying to append `<li>` tag at the top of drop down. but currently it is appending at bottom of `<ul>`.

i tried to add new `ul` tag but i think that is not good practice.

**html**

```
<ul class="dropdown notifications no-hover closed notilist">
 @foreach(Auth::user()->notifications->take(4) as $notification)
    @if(!empty($notification['data']['sender_name']))
<li class='dropdown-item'><b>{{$notification['data']['sender_name']}}</b> Bid on your Auction <b>{{$notification['data']['product_title']}}</b> of <b>{{$notification['data']['bid']}}$</b>
</li>
   @endif
  @endforeach
</ul>
```

**jquery**

```
Echo.private('App.User.'+userId)
 .notification((notification) => {
$('.notilist').append("<li class='dropdown-item'><b> "+notification.sender_name+"</b> Bid on your Auction  <b>"+notification.product_title+"</b>  of <b>"+notification.bid+"</b>$</li>")

 });
```

I want to append that new `<li>` tag at the top.

Comment: use `prepend()` method instead `append()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you can look at the jQuery method `prepend`. Here's the link [Prepend](https://api.jquery.com/prepend/)

```
$('.notilist').prepend("<li class='dropdown-item'>text should be here</li>");
```

Comment: Please [avoid link only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info). Answers that are "barely more than a link to an external site” [may be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).